# Not running project only build successful

Tags: java, netbeans-8

My project is not running , only giving build successful  message in the output window

```
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
run-deploy:
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run it?

Comment: Open a web browser and see if your project is deployed. If you don't know the url,  you can mouse over the server in the services window and add the contextpath from the projects run settings.   If it is then it is probably just your settings for starting a web-browser are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try Press Shift-F6 to "run file", not "run project".